# Upon jQuery onClick, incrementing a PHP variable?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a link like this: `<a href="javascript:window.print();">Print</a>`. I'm trying to increment a PHP variable when that is clicked. I could technically do it by submitting a form, but I'm sure there is an easier way. Any ideas?

Comment: And that PHP variable is where (relative to the page with the ANCHOR)?

Comment: PHP Variable? As in something that only exists for the duration of PHP executing (with the exception of a session/cookie). Are you sure you don't mean a DB variable, accessible through PHP?

Comment: Yeah like @Brad Christie and @g.d.d.c have mentioned, use a database and AJAX. JQuery is good for that http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Remove the js from the href and add an onclick="incrementFunction();return false" to the attributes. That function then calls the JQuery AJAX that runs a PHP script, which updates the database. A new value (+1 hopefully) is returned and displayed.

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript is Client Side.  PHP is Server Side.  If you want to affect a PHP Variable with a JavaScript event you must issue an AJAX call of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to persist a variable like this using some sort of database. You can then issue an AJAX call to a small server-side file that increments a value in that database.

On your HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#print').click(function() {
            $.getJSON('http://somewhere.com/increment.php', null, function(data) {
                console.log('remote increment script returned: ' + data);
            });
            window.print();
        });
    });
</script>
<a href="javascript: void 0;" id="print">Print</a>
```

Then, server-side in `/increment.php` (I assumed MySQL, but you could use something else like Redis for this as well):

```
// database connection goes here
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET stat_value = stat_value + 1 WHERE stat_key = 'prints'", $some_database_connection);
mysql_close($some_database_connection);
die( $result ? 'true' : 'false' );
```